# Dropdown onchange load another dropdown MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am populating two Dropdown lists (Category and SubCategory) in my view.

I am doing that thru my controller, and i want the Dropdown of SubCategory to be populated depending on the selected item from Category.

Any suggestion how to do this, and is there a better and more efficient way to populate the dropdowns?

```
Controller:

public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        EntryViewModel model = (from subcat in dc.SubCategory
                                join en in dc.Entry on subcat.SubCategoryId equals en.SubCategoryId
                                join cat in dc.Category on subcat.CategoryId equals cat.Id
                                where en.Id == id
                                select new EntryViewModel {
                                    Id = en.Id,
                                    Title = en.Title,
                                    Username = en.Username,
                                    Password = en.Password,
                                    Url = en.Url,
                                    Description = en.Description,
                                    CategoryId = cat.Id,
                                    CategoryName = cat.Name,
                                    SubCategoryId = subcat.SubCategoryId,
                                    SubCategoryName = subcat.Name
                                }).First();

        string selectedCat = (from cat in dc.Category
                           join en in dc.SubCategory on cat.Id equals en.SubCategoryId
                           where cat.Id == en.SubCategoryId
                           select cat.Name).First();

        ViewBag.SubjectNameCat = new SelectList(dc.Category, "Id", "Name", selectedCat);

        string selected = (from cat in dc.SubCategory
                           join en in dc.Entry on cat.SubCategoryId equals en.SubCategoryId
                           where en.Id == id
                           select cat.Name).First();

        ViewBag.SubjectName = new SelectList(dc.SubCategory, "SubCategoryId", "Name", selected);

        return View(model);
    }
```

View: Shownig just the dropdown lists for simplicity

```
<div class="editor-label">
        Category
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CategoryId, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.SubjectNameCat,
               new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        SubCategory
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SubCategoryId, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.SubjectName,
               new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
```

Comment: Google [mvc cascading dropdownlist](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=mvc+cascading+dropdownlist&oq=mvc+cascading+drop&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0j69i60j0l3.6405j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=2&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8). There are plenty of examples of how do do this. As a side note the last parameter of your `SelectList` code is pointless. The selected values of the dropdowns will be the values of `model.CategoryId` and `model.SubCategoryId`

Answer (score 0):

@PetarS Try this awesome plugin that works best for me. 
https://github.com/rajkaimal/CascadingDropDown